# Print a word after a piped command output to the same line

Tags: bash, pv

I have a command pipeline using pv (pipe viewer). I would like print 'done' after the pipeline output in the same line. I use pv, and it has a parameter -c/--cursor which perhaps could provide this, but I cannot find out how to use it. The documentation is very concise and I don't find examples. -c, --cursor do not accept parameter.

Example

```
for a in {1,2,3,4}; do echo $a; sleep 2; done | tee -a log.txt | pv -name "Test" -w 80 -cls 4 > /dev/null; echo done
```

Either using -c or not 'done' will be printed in the next row, but during the process there is a difference: using -c, cursor is in the end of the progress bar.

Comment: Do you mean you want to show `[===  ] 75% done`, or do you want to write "done" on the same line when it's finished?

Comment: @thatotherguy when it is finished